# Change cell color based on another cell value

Tags: vba, excel

In a workbook I have, the D column has a formula in it to derive the last six digits of a value in column C. These columns are located in a sheet titled "JE". I have a dynamic SQL connected query that has values in the A column. That query is located in a sheet titled "required_refs". I essentially, want to write: If the value in the D column cell matches/equals any of the values in that query in sheet "required_refs", turn the F column cell red in sheet JE.

Example: If cell D10 has a value that equals any of the values in column A in "required_refs", turn cell F10 red. In addition, if cell D13 has a value that matches/equals a value in column A in sheet "required_refs", turn F13 red. And so on.

Here is the code I tried. I added it in Sheet "JE":
Code:

```
  Sub ChangeCellColor()

    Dim ref_code As Range: Set ref_code = Range("D7:D446").Value
    Dim refCode_Confirm As Range: Set refCode_Confirm = Worksheets("required_refs").Range("A:A").Value
    Dim colorChange As Range: Set colorChange = Worksheets("required_refs").Range("A:A")

    For Each cell In ref_code
        If cell.Value = refCode_Confirm.Value Then
            Range("F7:F446").ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Next cell
        End If
    End Sub
```

Currently, this code just doesn't do anything. It doesn't turn the F column cell red. I've asked a question similar to this but, the workbook I'm using has changed a bunch since then, and this question is a bit more simple than the previous one.
If anyone could help, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Could you try to change `Range("F7:F446").ActiveCell` to `cell`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of issues.

1. `.Value` returns a basic type, like a string or long. You can't assign this to a range variable.
2. Your `End If` and `Next cell` statements are swapped around. ***Always*** use correct indentation so these errors become more obvious.
3. You have an undeclared variable `cell`. This can potentially cause bugs. In the VBE, turn on the `Tools > Options > Editor > Required Variable Declaration` option to force the use of `Option Explicit` in new modules.

Fixing these issues leads us to this:

```
Sub ChangeCellColor()

  Dim cell As Range
  Dim ref_code As Range: Set ref_code = Range("D7:D446")
  Dim refCode_Confirm As Range: Set refCode_Confirm = Worksheets("required_refs").Range("A:A")
  Dim colorChange As Range: Set colorChange = Worksheets("required_refs").Range("A:A")

  For Each cell In ref_code
    If cell.Value = refCode_Confirm.Value Then
      Range("F7:F446").ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
  Next cell

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, it still doesn't work as you can't compare a single value directly against a column of values in VBA.

This following code corrects this remaining issue. Note the choosing of good meaningful names as well as the use of [RVBA](http://www.xoc.net/standards/rvbanc.asp) for the variables. This is a good tip for how to avoid making similar errors. Also note the use of `.Value2` instead of `.Value`. This is *highly* recommended.

```
Sub ChangeCellColor()

  Dim rngRef As Range
  Dim rngRefsToCheck As Range: Set rngRefsToCheck = Range("D7:D446")
  Dim rngRequiredRefs As Range: Set rngRequiredRefs = Worksheets("required_refs").Columns("A")
  Dim rngColorChangeRequired As Range: Set rngColorChangeRequired = Columns("F")

  For Each rngRef In rngRefsToCheck
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(rngRef.Value2, rngRequiredRefs, 0)) Then
      rngColorChangeRequired.Cells(rngRef.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
  Next rngRef

End Sub
```

The best and fastest way to achieve the color change would be to use Advanced Filters, thus avoiding the need to loop. However, since you're still learning the basics, I've shown the looping version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and correction. I appreciate it. Are you suggesting that using an advanced filter, rather than vba, would be a better way to accomplish the cell color change? Thanks again!

Comment: @anve Sorry. I meant using an advanced filter ***in*** VBA. It would, of course, require either a change to your worksheet by adding an extra four rows above the data, or doing so temporarily in VBA.If the time to run the loop in your case is acceptable then there's no need to go to the extra level of complexity. I was speaking in the general case, and as something to think about the next time you do something similar.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I incorporated your code into my "JE" sheet and unfortunately, it doesn't turn the F column cell red. It doesn't cause any errors or anything.  But, I will continue to investigate and see if I can get it to work. Thanks again for the assistance!

Comment: @anve Make sure you actually *did* put the code into the `JE` sheet module. The way I've written it, it will *only* work there. Anywhere else it will do exactly what you're observing - no errors, but no change. And make sure that the values are stored the same way on both sheets. Either all as numbers, or all as text.

Comment: I have placed the code _inside_ sheet "JE" module. The values i'm checking are derived from a formula `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(MID(C7,16,6),required_refs!A:A,1,0)),"no ref",VLOOKUP(MID(C7,16,6),required_refs!A:A,1,0))` and they are being checked against a dynamic SQL query inisde a column that's datatype, in Excel is General. Both columns are General. Should I change the datatype of those columns to make them all either numbers, or text?

Comment: @anve Not *absolutely* sure what type the SQL query cells are, but I suspect they might be numbers. You can tell by checking the horizontal alignment of the values. With no user selected horizontal alignment, if the values are right aligned, they are numbers. If they are left aligned, with possibly a red error triangle in the top left corner, they are text. Not sure how to convert the SQL values, if they are numbers, to text. To convert the formula text values to numbers use the `VALUE()` function.(Changing the formula column to Text/Number will have no effect. Not sure about the SQL column.)